# Circular image and background color fails on printing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, css, printing

When printing the page, the user needs to uncheck the "Heders and Footers" to have the image in circular format, and needs to check the "Background colors and images" to have the background color on paper.

[image]

```
@@media print {
    img {
        border: 5px solid rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
        border-radius: 100px;
    }
    table {
        background-color: rgba(244,244,244,1.00);
        font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Sans', 'DejaVu Sans', 'Verdana', 'sans-serif';
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #a9a9a9;
    }
}
```

People using default settings on printing. How can I make the image look circular and background color do the rgba(244,244,244,1.00) as default.

Comment: Whats with the `@@` ?

Comment: View engine is Razor. That's the why doubled it

Answer (score 0):

Use `IMG` tags. `IMG`tags are used for when someone wants his page to be printed, `background-image` are not printed by default.